# replace any of these characters with nothing: ''

Tags: javascript, regex

```
somevar = ' 150,00 $';
someothervar = '$25.0;
```

I want to remove dollar signs, spaces, commas or dots.

Tried `somevar.replace(/('$'|' '|,|\.)/g,'');` returned  `15000 $` (leading space).

So it looks like the comma is being removed but not everything else?

I could go like this:

```
somevar.replace(/\$/g,'').replace(/ /g,'').replace(/,/g,'')
```

But surely there's a more 'elegant' way?

Comment: What is the expected output? `150,00 $` -> `150` or `15000`?

Comment: are you completely sure about dots and commas?

Comment: `/\D/g` is the best way, but be careful, one day if your occasionally remove the decimals from your response... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `/[$,.\s]/g`:

```
' 150,00 $'.replace(/[$,.\s]/g, '');
// "15000"

'$25.0'.replace(/[$,.\s]/g, '');
// "250"
```

Your regular expression wasn't working because you needed to escape the `$` character, and remove the single quotes. You could have used: `/\$| |,|\./g`.

Alternatively, you could also just replace all non-digit character using `/\D/g`:

```
' 150,00 $'.replace(/\D/g, '');
// "15000"

'$25.0'.replace(/\D/g, '');
// "250"
```

Comment: That `/\D/g` suggestion was posted by Roberto before you did.

Comment: @stribizhev I answered ~3 minutes earlier than him. I didn't even see his answer until I saw your comment. Are you suggesting that I should remove that or something?

Comment: ".. because you needed to escape the $ character" - perhaps add a clarification on why *you* don't need to?

Comment: Thanks for this answer it really clears things up and sounds/looks obvious written down

Answer (score 2):

I would:

```js
var somePriceString = "$$2.903.5,,,3787.3";

console.log(somePriceString.replace(/\D/g,''));
```

If I wanted to remove any non-digit character.